# Do I have to release memory manually when doing tailend recursion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-management

say I have

```
function doWithRetry(retries=5) {
  let bigObject = new BigObject()
  try {
    return doSomething(bigObject)
  } catch (e) {
    if(retries) {
      return doWithRetry(retries-1)
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm thinking that as I try and try again, the callstack continues to grow, so my question is whether the `bigObject`s on my stack of function calls are ineligible for garbage collection until the entire stack unwinds, even though they aren't really reachable, and thus I should be deleting `bigObject` from the local function scope before doing my recursive function call?

Comment: Are you asking whether the bigObject remains on the stack after every tail recursive call or are you asking whether why it stays on the stack after each call?

Comment: Remember that recursion is always more difficult than one thinks it should be.  It also can be very computationally expensive, so if there is a way to avoid that by using a different approach, that is always better.  That said, many people are interested in recursion, so good question.  My own definition for recursion:  A recursive program is a program that calls itself recursively.

Comment: tail-call or not, no common JS environment implements tail-call optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript engine is not smart enough to detect that `bigObject` is likely to be used after a recursive call ends or not, so I guess you have to set it to `null` or `undefined` before the recursive call, to make it effectively unreachable and collectable. As pointed in the comments, another solution consists in instantiating it into the `catch` block, since it's declared with `let`

Comment: You can also limit the scope. Move `bigObject` into the try block